# Creating a prefab from a gameobject in scene by using Prefabutiliy.CreatePrefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, destroy, gameobject

I have a gameobject in scene that has children and components. I want to save it as a prefab and later delete the gameobject by using c# scripting. I have a basic script that handles this situation :

```
GameObject gObject = Gameobject.Find(name);
if (gObject != null)
{
    PrefabUtility.CreatePrefab("Assets/Models/" + data + ".prefab", gObject, ReplacePrefabOptions.Default);
    Destroy(gObject);
}
```

This code works well. But only saves transform components while creating the prefab. Mesh info of the gameobject is lost after CreatePrefab operation.Is there a way to create a prefab that includes all components of the gameobject?

Comment: You might find more answers on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I believe that you need to use instantiate to copy the full prefab -> https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

Comment: what version of unity are you using. After testing you exact code the prefab has all of it components just as they are suppose to be. Also are you running this code in the editor or a build. PrefabUtility is strictly for editor use.

Comment: I an using version 5.3.5f1. For now this code is running in the editor but I was planning this functionality to run in the build . But as you say it is not possible to use PrefabUtility in build. Do you know another way to create a prefab from gameobjects ?

Comment: You can't (afaik) create prefabs at runtime. They are an in-editor construct only.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specifically save the mesh inside the prefab.

```
Object prefab = PrefabUtility.CreatePrefab(...
AssetDatabase.AddObjectToAsset(yourMesh, prefab);
Destroy(gObject);
```

If you have multiple meshes, you will need to AddObjectToAsset each of them individually.

Re: your comment: There is no need to have this functionality in a build. You can create a GameObject at runtime with all the components and meshes you want, then clone it using Instantiate just as you would with a prefab.